# javascript run all if statements at once

Tags: javascript, html

Below is the code i am trying, i have to validate all fields at once, return error message once that dismissable alert, i want all the if statements to work all at once but only 1st if statement is executing and once if statments else part is satisfied then only next if statement is executed i want all the if statements to work at once and then only return true for validate function.
main.html

```html
<form name="register" method="post" onsubmit="return validate()" novalidate>
<div id="sign_up_errors"></div>
name <input type="text" name="whole_name" id="whole_name" />
email <input type="email" name="e_mail" id="e_mail" />
password <input type="password" name="pass_word" id="pass_word" />
<button type="submit" name="sign_up">Sign Up</button>
</form>
<script>
var sign_up_errors = document.getElementById('sign_up_errors');

        var whole_name = document.getElementById('whole_name');
        var e_mail = document.getElementById('e_mail');
        var pass_word = document.getElementById('pass_word');

        function validate(){
            if (whole_name.value.trim().length == 0) {
                whole_name.style.borderBottomColor = "red";
                whole_name.style.borderBottomWidth = "5px";
                register_errors.innerHTML = "<div class='alert alert-danger alert-dismissible'> <button type='button' class='btn-close' data-bs-dismiss='alert'> </button> ALl the fields that are underlined are required</div>";
                return false;
            } else{
                whole_name.style.borderStyle = "none";
   }
            if (e_mail.value.trim().length == 0) {
                e_mail.style.borderBottomColor = "red";
                e_mail.style.borderBottomWidth = "5px";
                register_errors.innerHTML = "<div class='alert alert-danger alert-dismissible'> <button type='button' class='btn-close' data-bs-dismiss='alert'> </button> ALl the fields that are underlined are required</div>";
                return false;
            } else{
                e_mail.style.borderStyle = "none";
}
            if (pass_word.value.trim().length == 0) {
                pass_word.style.borderBottomColor = "red";
                pass_word.style.borderBottomWidth = "5px";
                register_errors.innerHTML = "<div class='alert alert-danger alert-dismissible'> <button type='button' class='btn-close' data-bs-dismiss='alert'> </button> ALl the fields that are underlined are required</div>";
                return false;
            } else {
                pass_word.style.borderStyle = "none";
}
        }</script>
```

Comment: The problem is with the `return` statements each if block. As per the code which you wrote: the function stops and returns false as soon as it hits a field that is empty, and it doesn't have a chance to check the other fields.

Comment: Instead of `return`ing after every check, store your validation state in a variable and return that variable at the end of your function.

Answer (score 4):

To make all the *if* statements execute and collect errors, you should accumulate the errors and return `true` at the end of the final *if* statement:

```
....
....
function validate() {
  var errors = [];

  if (whole_name.value.trim().length == 0) {
    whole_name.style.borderBottomColor = "red";
    whole_name.style.borderBottomWidth = "5px";
    errors.push("Name is required");
  } else {
    whole_name.style.borderStyle = "none";
  }

  if (e_mail.value.trim().length == 0) {
    e_mail.style.borderBottomColor = "red";
    e_mail.style.borderBottomWidth = "5px";
    errors.push("Email is required");
  } else {
    e_mail.style.borderStyle = "none";
  }

  if (pass_word.value.trim().length == 0) {
    pass_word.style.borderBottomColor = "red";
    pass_word.style.borderBottomWidth = "5px";
    errors.push("Password is required");
  } else {
    pass_word.style.borderStyle = "none";
  }

  if (errors.length > 0) {
    var errorHtml = "<div class='alert alert-danger alert-dismissible'><button type='button' class='btn-close' data-bs-dismiss='alert'></button>";
    errorHtml += "<ul>";
    for (var i = 0; i < errors.length; i++) {
      errorHtml += "<li>" + errors[i] + "</li>";
    }
    errorHtml += "</ul></div>";

    sign_up_errors.innerHTML = errorHtml;
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
  ....
  ....
```

Comment: I am still a learner in web development , i started a few weeks ago, i am still learning, anyways thanks for your help. I have another request can i ask?